# PHP readdir(): sort folder first and then files

Tags: php

How to sort the folders first, then the files with the readdir?

```
if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
        
        $file . "\n";
    }
    closedir($dh);
}
```

need

```
..
dir/
dir/
file
file
file
```

The folders can contain more than 50K files and sub-folders, I don't want to store the results in an array (scandir, etc.) for performance reasons.

Thanks

Comment: How can you sort them without storing them in an array? 50K is nothing and won't hurt performance at all.

Comment: By the way, when you say 'sort', do you mean storing them in a sorted manner on disk?

Comment: have look at PHP `glob`.